# Data Flow level Programming in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I made the following program for displaying no of days in the user provided month. And to check whether the year user entered is leap year or not. I am trying to make the program on data flow level. I don't know whether I can use if/else in data flow level in Verilog. The following program is giving me errors at the notified place.

```
module LeapYear(year,month,leapOrNot,Days);

input year,month;

output leapOrNot,Days;
 // error here
      if((year&400)==0) && ((year % 100)!==0 || (year & 4)==0)begin
       leapOrNot=1;
       end
  else

if(month==4 || month==6|| month==9|| month==11)begin
    Days=30;
end else
    if(month==1 || month==3|| month==5|| month==7|| month==8|| month==10|| month==12)begin
         Days=31;
  end  else
        if(month==2 && leapOrNot==1) begin
            Days=29;
     end   else begin
              Days=28;
              end

  endmodule
```

Please tell me what is the reason for this error.
There error is

```
 ** Error: C:/Modeltech_5.7f/examples/LeapYear.v(9): near "if": syntax error
```

Regards

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what the error message is?

Comment: I am updated the question. And please tell me if it is allowed to use if/else in data flow level programming

Answer (score 3):

Your code has many, many problems. Balancing parentheses is among the least of them.

First of all, an `if` statement can only appear in the body of a behavioral (`always`) statement/block. This is the cause of the error message you listed.

Secondly, module input ports can't be integers, which is what you seem to be assuming. Multi-bit values need to be given explicit widths.

There are also many other syntax, logic and style issues, too numerous to get into. Try the following code instead.

```
module LeapYear (year, month, leapOrNot, Days);

input [15:0] year;    // 0-65535
input  [3:0] month;   // 1-12

output leapOrNot;
reg    leapOrNot;

output Days;
reg    Days;

always @* begin
  if ((year % 400) == 0 && (year % 100) != 0 && (year % 4) == 0) begin
    leapOrNot <= 1;
  end else begin
    leapOrNot <= 0;
  end
end

always @* begin
  if (month==2) begin
    if (leapOrNot==1) begin
      Days <= 29;
    end else begin
      Days <= 28;
    end
  end else if (month==4 || month==6 || month==9 || month==11) begin
    Days <= 30;
  end else begin
    Days <= 31;
  end
end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
    if((year&400)==0) && ((year % 100)!==0 || (year & 4)==0) begin
//    ^             ^
       leapOrNot=1;
     end
```

The two parenthesis that I marked in the code are matching each other, making the tool think this is the complete condition for the `if` statement. The tool expects the `begin` to be immediately after the close-parenthesis.

According to [The Verilog Golden Reference Guide](http://www.fpga.com.cn/hdl/training/verilog%20reference%20guide.pdf), it's required to put a parenthesis around the whole conditional expression in the `if` statement.

```
    if (((year&400)==0) && ((year % 100)!==0 || (year & 4)==0)) begin
//     ^                                                      ^
//     Added                                                  Added
       leapOrNot=1;
    end
```